# Tutorial on user and group management in Linux?

Tags: linux, user-management, tutorial

Is there a good tutorial out there on how to do user and group management in Linux?

For example in Ubuntu; I've been trying to find how to alter GECOS information about each user on command line, but there is no man page about it.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is generally not a good idea, as the tutorials get out of date quickly, and are of little use to future visitors. Instead, if you have a specific question about where you're stuck, feel free to [ask another question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) outlining exactly where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the most fancy way of doing things, but I mostly just use VI when editing these things.  Of course, I use `useradd` to create a user.  But then I'll use `vi` to make changes.

For Ubuntu, I found a [reference](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Jaunty#User_Administration) on how to manage users.

I don't know if Ubuntu has this command, but in Red Hat/Fedora and related distributions, there's a command `system-config-users` which is pretty self-explanatory.